# Нерекурсивный обход дерева в глубину

Tags: алгоритм

Знаю, что есть такой способ. Поиск решения выполняется с помощью 2х (вроде бы) списков. Но в гугле инфы почти не нашёл. Дерево не бинарное, а шестиричное, если так можно выразиться. Но думаю, этот алгоритм в любом будет работать.

Comment: Это называется «k-дерево с k=6» =).

Comment: Первая ссылка из поделки Сереги Брина!
http://pco.iis.nsk.su/ICP/Practice/dd8-3/node7.html

Answer (score 1):

Ну так выполните обычный нерекурсивный обход в глубину, как в любой книжке по теории графов учат.
Два списка — это, конечно, перебор, а вот стек пригодится.

*Или я чего-то не уловил?*

Comment: Стек — для поиска в глубину, очередь — в ширину.